# What is the User Actions History Best practice?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

In Our company we want to log User history in our web application,for example when a user come to a page and save something (Call save stored proc) we log this action some where and ....
First solution is after call any Stored procedure(SP) ,call the SP of "Insert_Log_Table" this decrease performance,
Second is in ORM use multithreading and call "Insert_Log_Table" in another thread and ...

we cant use second solution for some problems in our application architecture,so now what should we do?
how could have concurrency or multithreading,becuase we dont want the user wait for insert into log table and ..?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the second solution? It's a piece of cake to run a method in another thread. You don't need to handle locking, race conditions or other threading issues. It's just an append-only log. And nothing will even happen if the method fails somehow (so that nothing can catch the failure), because, again, it's just a log.

See this sample:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Logger log = new logger();
                log.Log("...");
            });

    t.Start();
```

But as a side note I'll recommend you - don't use SQL for this. Use other robust and proven solutions like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), or revert to fast memory-based (with eventual disk persistency) NoSQL database like [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Would you care to explain why SQL is not robust or proven? If he already has a database there then he should use it. Why introduce another technology he might not be familiar wit?

Comment: I didn't say SQL is not robust; I said there are more robust solutions for logging. log4net is a tool equipped with a lot of configuration options especially for logging, including trimming, formatting, saving call stack, persisting using a variety of options (continuous, one-in-a-day, event-log, file based, db based etc.)

Comment: thanks for replay,but my project is too big to change source,its more comfortable and Low Cost to change sql.after recording history I want to show it to User,so I prefer the log data be in sqlDatabase.is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: See the beginning of my answer.